# iOS BLE Scanning with (user) killed App

Tags: ios, bluetooth

I am trying to find out if I can have a terminated iOS App register for Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) events. I already got the app working in background mode while being suspended.

I also read in the official documentation about state restauration and preservation for killed Apps. As far as I can see the documentation always seems to refer to apps killed by the system due to memory shortage.

My question is whether or not there is a similar possibility for apps that were terminated by the user. I would like to (re)-create my app whenever a BLE peripheral is close.

Comment: In iOS able to BLE scanning after kill app by user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**N.B** [This may no longer be true on iOS 11](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1962/_index.html), but I haven't had a chance to test it out yet.

If the user kills your app (via the task switcher), then it will not be relaunched until the user explicitly launches it.

So that means, no, you cannot relaunch your app with beacon proximity after the user kills your app.

Comment: I have one ios app(created by objective c - for BLE), its working after kill app by user.

Comment: So iOS is relaunching your app in response to BLE events after the user kills it? Is this on iOS 10? This doco says that won’t happen on iOS 11: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1962/_index.html

Comment: Yes, i was tested in only ios 10, but not tested in ios 11. So i am not sure for app is running after kill app by user in iOS 11. Thanks.

Comment: I have an App that will Restart on iOS 11.3 triggered by the presence of the LE device I wish to connect to. Developed initially on iOS 9.3. It's done through adding the "Background Processing" tag to your app. The user has to "train it" for just a couple days (launching it manually) and after that iOS will reliably launch the app even is the user killed it.

Comment: Is this behaviour new in 11.3? That contradicts the linked documentation.

Answer (score 0):

In ios possible to BLE scan and other works after kill app by user.
Tested in iOS 10(its working fine).
Not tested in iOS 11(not sure for app is run after kill app by user in iOS 11).

Comment: also i trying to implement in demo app, i have not any code for this.

Comment: if you get any solution, please share with me.

Comment: Okey. I hope I will find.

Comment: Hey any one have solution if App terminated forcefully by system or user can we connect or scan new peripheral devices?